# Public IPv4 subnet: ping result in "Destination Host Prohibited"

Tags: routes, ipv4, netmask

I got a new FTTC connection few days ago, along with 8 additional IPv4 addresses, say `89.89.233.104/29` (don't test them, they're fake). The ISP modem has *89.89.233.110* (which is the default gateway), so available for use are from *.105* to *.109*.

I attach my linux computer to the modem LAN, configure with

```
ifconfig eth0 89.89.233.108 netmask 255.255.255.248
route add default gw 89.89.233.110
```

From outside I can ping 110 and 108, but from my desktop if I ping outside I get the following:

```
# ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 89.89.233.110 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Prohibited
From 89.89.233.110 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Prohibited
From 89.89.233.110 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Prohibited
```

How is this possible? Why from outside I can be pinged (and so my host is replying to the outside world), but from inside I cannot access internet? I disabled every firewall or whatever *enhanced* feature I could find on the ISP modem. I tried pinging and tracerouting even ISP's DNS, thinking I could have some DNS restrictions but nothing changed.

I made every possible test, using Linux, Windows 7, pfSense (FreeBSD), they all give the same result. I called the ISP and they're coming to make some test themselves, buf if any suggestion can come from the community I'll be happy to test.

Oh, on a side note, we also have a single *Point-to-Point* IP on the modem, and internet works perfectly from there (that is: getting DHCP from the modem itself). The modem is connected in *Bridged + Routed* mode, so apparently it's *routing* but not correctly *bridging*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was as supposed a modem problem. After 3h the ISP technician replaced it nd magically everything started to work

Comment: Makes sense. The modem is probably also the router and was (mis)configured to prohibit outbound ping requests. The tech replaced it because that's faster than troubleshooting it.

Comment: Also because those custom firmware are barely impossible to debug. It's not like a Cisco appliance, just a black box...

Comment: I had a similar problem ("Destination Host Prohibited") when trying to ping an Internet address from a double-NATted network. The problem in my case was that the router directly connected to the Internet had NAT disabled for the IP address on which the second router WAN was configured. So, from behind the second router I could ping that second router, the first router, but not the Internet. After applying a configuration change on the first router that enabled NAT on its whole LAN IP range, pinging from behind the second router to the Internet started to work, as well as Internet connectivity.